# How to assign user-defined indices to <md-tab> elements of angular material?

Tags: angularjs, angular-material

```
<md-tabs>
     <md-tab label="Tab #1"></md-tab>
     <md-tab label="Tab #2"></md-tab>
     <md-tab label="Tab #3"></md-tab>
</md-tabs>
```

`<md-tab`> elements within the parent `<md-tabs>` are assigned some indices by default starting from `0`. So, in the above case, the three tabs will have indices 0, 1 and 2 respectively. What I want to do is, assign some different number as an index to a tab. This number can be later used by me to activate a tab using `md-selected` attribute. For some reason I don't want to use the default indices.

To be specific, I am displaying various categories( dairy, grocery, bakery, etc.) as tabs and I want each tab to get an index equal to the Id of the category displayed by that tab. These tabs are fetched from the database.

I have no idea how to make these tabs attain some indices other than the default one they get.

Is there any way to assign user-defined indices to the tabs?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There is no way to assign user-defines indices to the `<md-tab>` elements.
However if the tabs are generated by `<ng-repeat>` then `$index` can be set to a value that we prefer.